# Why is my Azure node.js app becoming unresponsive?

Tags: node.js, azure, crash, health-check

I recently deployed a Node.js Backend Service to Azure and have the following problem. The service becomes unresponsive after a certain amount of time, and only comes back to life if a external request is sent. The problem is, that it takes about 3 minutes for the Container to start back up and actually return the request. I'm running Node 14 LTS. I also added a health check yesterday, but azure simply doesn't bother actually keeping the app alive, here is the metric off azure[image]

I verified azure is actually trying to reach the correct endpoint, and it does. I also have "Always On" enabled. I also verified that the app itself, is not crashing. I log every request and all of a sudden requests are no longer received, which means the health endpoint doesn't respond either, but it does not result in a container restart. It just waits for an external request to appear and then decides to start everything back up, which takes too long.

I feel like it's some kind of configuration issue, because the app itself is not very complex and I never experienced crashes when doing local development.

Comment: Which tier you use, basic or Free, Standard?

Comment: I'm using the Free Tier

Comment: This is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Where can I exactly read up on this?

Comment: Please wait, I search offical doc for u.

Comment: If my solution inspires or helps you, could you mark my answer as accepted , Tks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official document tells us that the Free pricing tier you are currently using, Always on does not take effect.

[How do I decrease the response time for the first request after idle time?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time)

[image: pic]

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I just realized that I didn't properly see which option was checked, because the whole thing is greyed out and I thought 'On' was selected. Thanks for the answer though.